# Cannot correctly compare two numbers

Tags: c++

```
unsigned long long value = 0;

bool result = value >= std::numeric_limits<signed int>::min();
```

This should give true but gives false? Why and how can I fix it?

Comment: The answer is the same as for your last question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692882/bug-in-boost-check).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The int converts to an unsigned int for comparison. You could cast your `unsigned long long` to a `long long`.

5/9:

> Many binary operators that expect
>   operands of arithmetic or enumeration
>   type cause conversions and yield
>   result types in a similar way. The
>   purpose is to yield a common type,
>   which is also the type of the result.
>   This pattern is called the usual
>   arithmetic conversions, which are
>   defined as follows:

...

> Then, if
>   either operand is unsigned long the
>   other shall be converted to unsigned
>   long.

...

> Otherwise, if either operand is
>   unsigned, the other shall be converted
>   to unsigned.

`unsigned long long` and `long long` are not standard types in c++03, but it's quite likely that the compiler will treat these types using the mechanisms defined above. The mentioned conversion rules would then cover this particular conversion.